# Enabling cors on petstore.swagger.io

Tags: swagger

I'm playing with the [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io), the pet store example, and the API there contains this message under each endpoint:

```
This is a cross-origin call. 
Make sure the server at petstore.swagger.io accepts POST requests from editor.swagger.io.
```

OK, so I go to http://petstore.swagger.io , but where exactly do I set the CORS there? I don't see it.

Thanks.